My boss's can't stop asking questions
Before two weeks, my boss started to tell me that he wants me to improve in two sides, one is scientific side, and two, my personality.
I liked that, I honestly welcomed what he said,but now things changed very bad (from my point of view). Now he's asking me lot of questions, scientific ones,and I'm not able to answer and his reaction is like you're not doing well enough. I'm not a button you click on and find a result, and he knows that. So now I'm thinking that he has other intentions, like he wants me to resign and say he resigned, it's not my fault, or things like that.
So what you think??
Shall I resign?

Your question is a bit difficult to follow. It seems you think that your boss wants to resign. Why? Do you think your boss will blame you?

Can you say which country you are working in?

We can't read his mind. Are these questions about things you should be learning about? Are they things where you can reply "I'm not sure but I think..." or "let me check and get back to you on that." Have you asked him if he's disappointed and what you should be doing about it if so, rather than trying to guess what he's thinking? Have you asked him how you are doing on the actual job and how you could be doing it better?

Well, I mean he wants me to go and read from zero and give him what I've learned in very short, he wants me to study tens of thousands of papers of books in short time and give him that yes I've learned this and I'll do this.

What I mean, does he wants me to resign?

I'm fresh, and I have this position for 6 months, and I noticed that this treatment happened after they brought a new one, I don't know I'm so confused, honestly I'm thinking to go tomorrow morning and tell him if you don't need me send me to another department or tell me go home, but I don't like such treatment

As it stands - this question is not answerable. Take some time to think about what you are doing and what your boss is doing, rewrite the question with some more detail and edit it. I think there is a good question in here - one we can probably help with - but we need more info.

@Pablor32 I strongly recomend you read workplace's question guide and edit your question accordingly.

You have a hard boss.
I do not know his reasons, doing this is probably a very ineffective way to let you resign. It depends on the country, but most likely he could fire you more easily, if he would really want.
The most important reason, why he probably not want to fire you: wanting to fire something is not what we happily do. You are going to break his career. You are going to take away his daily living. Yes, sometimes you need to do, but that is not a pleasant thing also for the boss. If you are going to fire someone, you won't ask things from him hours long. Actually, a possible signature of that a boss wants to fire you, that he seems ignoring you.
The possible reasons:

He has same uncommon mental buildup. He is crazy, in short.
He might experimenting with some uncommon psychological-behavioral practice. For example, he has read a book.
He is bored and actually he see a relaxation in you by talking with you.

Very likely, you are not on an usual workplace.
If you have the habit to keep important things in secret, you are lost. That he will surely not tolerate.
Document everything what you did, or what you found, and point to the documentation.
If his questions are obstacling your work, then warn him that you want to do X ("X" is a task given to you by him before).
The only reason to have such an uncommon boss is that also the company is uncommon, and being uncommon makes likely, that you want to earn more. So, keep also your CV warm.
If he pays well, on some reason, then the decision is yours. I think it is unlikely, but making uncommon work for more money is more likely a happy thing. But I think it is more likely that you are underpaid.

Answer every question he asks even if incorrect.  But give an answer related to the question to see if he corrects it or is satisfied with the answer. This will let you know his true intentions on the series of questions.  Once you know, you then can do the next indicated thing.

Answering a question and giving an incorrect or inaccurate response is probably worse then being unable to answer the question

Agree with @donald; if you don't know, you should say you don't know. You can then say what your best guess is based on your current understanding, or you can offer to research it and get back to them. It is also a legitimate to say that, in order to make sure you are giving the right answer, it would help if you understood what the question behind the question is - that is, what problem they are trying to solve.
